# test a bash script with gradle

Tags: bash, testing, gradle, automated-tests

we're using gradle as build tool and for our java and ansible projects. Now I would like to test a bash script from within gradle as well.

Do you have any tipps/resources or better even an example how I can test a bash script using gradle? It can be as simple as executing the script and having the "test" pass, if the return value of the bash script under test is 0 or if the stdout or stderr contain certain strings (or don't contain them).

Thanx a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a Gradle task which stops tomcat server:

```
task stopTomcat(type:Exec) {
  workingDir '../tomcat/bin'

  //on windows:
  commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'stop.bat'

  //on linux
  commandLine './stop.sh'

  //store the output instead of printing to the console:
  standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

  //extension method stopTomcat.output() can be used to obtain the output:
  ext.output = {
    return standardOutput.toString()
  }
}
```

It's also a good example because there are a few useful directives in it.

In your case it would be something like:

```
task testFile(type:Exec) {
  workingDir '/home/user'
  commandLine './test.sh'
}
```

More information can be found [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html).

Comment: Thanx for your comment. I know how to execute a command, but how do I process the exit code of the bash-script (or other program) to make a "test" (not the build) fail?